# Is the interaction with the smart contract safe?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain

I am working with ethereum and I have a doubt. In a real case, can a user interact directly with a smart contract? Are there no dangers? For example: a user wants to book a trip. What happens in these cases? Does the transaction start from the user or is there an intermediate component that collects the data and transmits it (via transactions) to the smart contract?

Comment: the User sends the transaction directly to the contract (sort of), but there are dangers. Someone could trick your user to send an `input` to the contract that would make some kind of undesired action, like stealing tokens.

Comment: or there could be an Approval hack like this one: https://medium.com/dedaub/look-ma-no-source-hacking-a-defi-service-with-no-source-code-available-c40a6583f28f

Comment: TLDR, there are many dangers!

Comment: @Nulik so how can they be avoided? If a metamask or alternatively (web3.js + geth / parity) how do I prevent these attacks?

Comment: you can't avoid it, someone will be hacked eventually. It is about following security guidelines on the User side. It is not a developer's problem.

Comment: of course I am assuming your contract have no bugs, but if in doubt, go get a security audit service